# Why can I not install pip on windows 7?

Tags: python, django, installation

so I'm trying to install pip for python because I want to use django.
I've looked through the forum and plenty of others for about three days so I'm very frustrated because its probably an easy fix.

so ive set the environment/path and pythons working.

- I've got the `get-pip.py` file
- I have `Setuptools-34.3.1`

They are both in the scripts folder?

so if i use this in cmd it comes back like this;

```
            C:\Windows\system32>python
            Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (In
            tel)] on win32
            Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
            >>> python get-pip.py
              File "<stdin>", line 1
                python get-pip.py
                         ^
            SyntaxError: invalid syntax
            >>>
```

This comes back for anything i ask it to do.

After trying everything in the forums its just still not working I've even uninstalled and tried other versions of python.

if anyone could help i would appreciate it.

Comment: You are executing the command in the python console. Try it from the command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to run `python get-pip.py` inside python instead of in the command line.

instead:

```
C:\Windows\system32>python get-pip.py
...
```

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>python get-pip.py
python: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: You need to have `get-pip.py` in the directory where you're running it from.

Comment: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\get-pip.py 

This is where it is i keep moving it around but i just have no idea.
any suggestions?

Comment: Go to the scripts folder then and run it there

Comment: right, i think i've got it but it only has more errors. its asking me to up date pip so i run what its asking me too the i get ;

  Found existing installation: pip 7.1.2
    Uninstalling pip-7.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-7.1.2
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

and it goes on...